# Using cmd to start TabPy

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run some cmd commands using a .bat file. This will be ran on a server so we can use python with Tableau server. The .bat file needs to first start the command prompt then navigate to the target folder and run the activate.bat file. This starts my anaconda prompt window. In there, I execute tabpy to start tabpy.

These are the lines verbatim I have in my .bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd
/k cd C:\Users\John Smith\Anaconda3\Scripts
/k activate.bat
/k tabpy
pause
```

When I run this .bat, a cmd window opens but nothing happens. I'm new to cmd and kind of have no idea what I'm doing. I put this together after reading a couple random sites. Thanks in advance!

Just to clarify, If I go into cmd prompt and type the following in this order, I get what I want:

**cd C:\Users\Michael B Smith\Anaconda3\Scripts

activate.bat

tabpy**

I just need to duplicate that using a .bat file.

Comment: Yes, because `start cmd` just starts another `cmd.exe` process, which has got nothing to do with the script, or rather, the `cmd.exe` the script is running in. You seem to want to run the following commands within the new `cmd.exe` instance, so you should do `start "" /D "%UserProfile%\Anaconda3\Scripts" cmd /D /K call activate.bat ^& tabpy` (if `tabpy` is a batch file too, precede it with `call` also)…

Comment: Instead, if your intention is *not* to open a new `cmd.exe` after all, remove `start cmd`, remove all `/k` prefixes, replace `cd` by `cd /D`, precede `activate.bat` with `call`, and do the same for `tabpy` if it is a batch file too…

Comment: tabpy is not a .bat file; it is the "tabpy.exe" file;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tabpy` is a python script.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d C:\Users\John Smith\Anaconda3\Scripts
call activate.bat
py.exe tabpy
pause
```

Comment: tabpy is a .exe file

Comment: Squashman, I get: "'py.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error when I try it your way.

Comment: You literally don't know the difference between running a python script and running an executable?  My comment literally said if `TABPY` is a python script.  IF not then you wouldn't be using Python to launch another executable.  So obviously you would need to remove `py.exe`.

Comment: You were doing so well Squashman.